# Rails ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy with Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I used Single Table Inheritance to model out Stores, Tailors, Orders, and TailorOrders. Orders belong to a tailor, but I am not able to access the orders of a tailor in the rails console. There are multiple types of stores, and in the database the order has a `requester_id` and a `provider_id`. The tailor's relationship to an order will ALWAYS be a provider. The inheritance model looks like:

```
class Store
end

class Tailor < Store 
  has_many :orders
end

class Order 
  has_many :items
end 

class TailorOrders
   belongs_to :tailor, class_name: "Tailor", foreign_key: "provider_id"
end

class Item 
  belongs_to :order
end
```

I am able to get items that belong to an order, like so:

```
Order.first.items
#=>  [#<Item:0x007fe9f0cc8f58
  id: 1,
  order_id: 1,
  name: "Grey Pants",
  created_at: Tue, 13 Jun 2017 17:50:57 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 13 Jun 2017 17:50:57 UTC +00:00,
  type_id: 1>]
```

And, I am able to get the tailor from the order:

```
Order.first.tailor
#=> #<Tailor:0x007fe9f214b8b8
 id: 3,
 company_id: 3,
 primary_contact_id: 3,
 phone: "2121468958",
 street1: "640 Bennie Way",
 street2: "Apt. 533",
 city: "Carliefurt",
 state: "New Mexico",
 zip: "42439-4809",
 country: "Ukraine",
 created_at: Tue, 13 Jun 2017 17:50:56 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 13 Jun 2017 17:50:56 UTC +00:00,
 type: "Tailor",
 name: "Joe's on Main Street">
```

But, I CANT get the orders that belong to a tailor:

```
Tailor.first.orders 
#=> #<Order::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x3ff4f786e9e0>

Tailor.first.orders.first
#=> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column orders.tailor_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."tailor_id" ...
```

This error seems related to the database layout, as I described above, where the class Tailor is always a `provider` in order's db table.

Is there a way to access the orders through a tailor (a type of store, also a provider in orders table)? What I also want to accomplish is something along the lines of `Stores.first.orders.first.items`. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Set `foreign_key` option for `has_many :orders` association in the `Tailor` class. Now it expects that the foreign key is the `tailor_id` column in the `orders` table, which in your case is something different.

Comment: Do you have a column in the `orders` table which points to the `Tailor` it belongs to ?

Comment: @chumakoff it works! perfect thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I would just post the solution here in case anyone else runs into this. Per @chumakoff's comment, I simply adjusted the Tailor class like so:

Before

```
class Tailor < Store 
  has_many :orders
end
```

After

```
class Tailor < Store
  has_many :orders, foreign_key: "provider_id"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a migration for `AddTailorToOrders`. It should be like this

`rails g migration AddTailorToOrders tailor:references`

`class AddTailorReferenceToOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   add_reference :orders, :tailor, index: true
 end
end`

That would create a column `tailor_id` in Order table which references Tailor.

Comment: the db schema for orders does have a provider_id column, which is necessary in our case since tailors wouldnt be the only store that fulfills it